# Is it possible to launch an app when an NFC tag is scanned?

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, intentfilter

I have an NFC tag. I want to write an Android application that is automatically launched and gets data from NFC when the NFC tag is scanned with the phone.

This should work assuming that the device has NFC turned on and that there are no other applications running on the phone. I found some applications which can launch another application, but my application should work without such an additional application running in the background.

Is there any way to solve this task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get your app (actually *activity*) started upon scanning a tag, you need to add an appropriate intent filter to your app manifest.

If you want to start your app for just any tag, the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter is what you would want to use:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

This intent filter requires an additional XML resource file that defines the tag technologies that your app should listen to (note the `<meta-data ... />` tag **outside** the intent-filter). The available technologies are those in the namespace `android.nfc.tech.*`, currently:

- `android.nfc.tech.IsoDep`
- `android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic`
- `android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight`
- `android.nfc.tech.Ndef`
- `android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable`
- `android.nfc.tech.NfcA`
- `android.nfc.tech.NfcB`
- `android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode`
- `android.nfc.tech.NfcF`
- `android.nfc.tech.NfcV`

To discover just any tag, you would create an XML file like this (create the file as `xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml`):

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Note that you do not necessarily need to incude the other technologies as

- `IsoDep` implies either `NfcA` or `NfcB`,
- `MifareClassic` implies `NfcA`,
- `MifareUltralight` implies `NfcA`, and
- `Ndef` / `NdefFormatable` imply either `NfcA`, `NfcB`, `NfcF`, or `NfcV`.

The above intent filter will be triggered if there is no other app that has a better matching intent filter. A better match would be a match for the data type used on the tag. So, for instance, if your tag contains a URL (encapsulated in an NDEF message), an app that triggers on URLs will get precedence over your app. If you know the data type(s) used on your tags, you could also add a filter for those data type(s). For instance, to match just any "http://" and "https://" URL, you could use:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Similarly, if your tag contains the MIME type "application/vnd.com.example", you could use:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.example" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You could even combine multiple intent filters for one activity:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.example" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Finally, there is one more NFC-related intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, you would normally **not** use this intent filter in the manifest. It is meant as a fall-back only and will only ever be triggered if there is no other app triggering on the technology or the data of the scanned tag. So there is no need to add this intent-filter of you already trigger for the above-mentioned `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helped me. Now the app starts but with intent `android.intent.action.MAIN` and not `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` as expected. I got the `getIntent.getAction()` from `onCreate` because `onNewIntent` is never called when app opens on NFC detection. Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: @Sam see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into it. Your answer did it for me. I reordered the writing of NDEF records and it worked fine.
Just for curiosity, is there a link for documentation that indicates the order of writing  you mentioned in No.1 ?
Cheers~~

Comment: @Sam https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar

Answer (score 2):

Add following `intent-filter` to your main `activity` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<!-- main activity -->
<activity ...>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android-name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android-name="android.nfc.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</activity>
```

Now, when you tap your NFC tag to your phone, your application will be called and run.

Comment: Does it work if I turn off all application which are running in my phone? It looks like I restart my phone and touch NFC when phone is turned on, then app. will be launch. Is it possilbe?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it before, you just need to turn your NFC on.

Comment: `android-name` should be `android:name`, if anyone's not able to get their app to build.

Comment: How to read the value of the NFC tag?