# Launching activity with NDEF won't keep the Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, smartcard, ndef

I am using third party NFC library for communicating with my NFC Tag. I manage to launch my Activity with formatted NDEF on the Tag.
However, if I want to do further commmunication with the Tag, I am unable to do it, since it seems that I lost the intent, even if I call `getIntent()` in `onResume` method. I have also tried to call it in `onCreate()` but it also didn't work.

**MY CODE:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mLibInstance.startForeGroundDispatch();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume called.");
    //final Intent intent = getIntent();
    //setIntent(getIntent());
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New Intent discovered.");
    detectCardType(intent);
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

It runs all the methods (it comes to the `onNewIntent`) but the intent is actually  "lost",I cannot detect which CardType it is ( the library tells me it is Unknown Card ). However if I use it once the App is already opened, it detects the Tag correctly.

Do you guys have any suggestion on this ?

Thanks!

Comment: What intent (intent action, categories, extras) do you see in `onNewIntent()`? What does the NDEF message that you stored on the tag look like?

Comment: I have used application called TagWriter to write LaunchActivity NDEF and wrote in the package name of my Application and just tapped my card and it stored it. The Activity launches, but as said, I cannot communicate further with my Intent.

In android manifest I use only NDEF Tech Discovered.   How can I get more info what intent I see ?

Comment: See [Get NFC tag with NDEF Android Application Record (AAR)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802)