# Reading Array/Payload on NFC Tag?

Tags: android, arrays, nfc

I've edited my Manifest code and my Activity code again to reflect appropriate intent filter requirements. However, I'm still getting the same results. I'm unable to read my external record, and I don't know why? When I scan my tags with the NFC Tools app, I can see everything as I would expect. My code produces a NullPointer when it attempts to "read" my array and I have no idea why?

--------------BEGIN MANIFEST--------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bmt_01">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>   ///must be changed in build.gradle.


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data
                    android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
                    android:host="ext"
                    android:pathPrefix="/com.example.bmt_01:externaltype"
                    />
            </intent-filter>



        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

--------------END MANIFEST--------------------

--------------BEGIN MAIN ACTIVITY-------------

```
package com.example.bmt_01;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String currentPayload = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        //added the below lines, can delete if they don't work.
            NdefRecord payload = ((NdefMessage)rawMsgs[0]).getRecords()[0];
            String currentPayload = new String(payload.getPayload());


                if (currentPayload.equals("1"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Scan1: " + currentPayload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    String url = "http://www.google.com";
                    Intent l = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    l.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(l);
                }
                ///else
                ///{
                    if (currentPayload.equals("2"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Scan2: " + currentPayload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
                        Intent l = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        l.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(l);
                    }
                ///}
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Scan3: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

    private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Scan4: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Scan5: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        onNewIntent(getIntent());


    }
}
```

--------------END MAIN ACTIVITY---------------

**UPDATE***

I should add that my AAR functions correctly. When I have the above app installed on my phone, but do not have it open, my AAR automatically opens and launches the application when I scan my test tag. So, I'm able to "see" the AAR in the array, but NOT the external record.

I'm still unable to read the external record on my tag. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea.

Comment: What problem did you experience? Do you even get the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent? Did you properly register to receive the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent in your app manifest?

Comment: I believe my manifest is configured correctly. My problem is that I'm unable to capture the value of "payloadString". I think I'm reading the array incorrectly. I'm planning on abandoning the "for" loop. Essentially, all I'm trying to do is read the external record and send the user to a website corresponding to the value of that record. ie, if payloadString = 1, go to www.yahoo.com. If payloadString = 2, go to www.google.com.

Comment: Then the code you had before should have delivered the `payloadString` just fine (though not in a very elegant or efficient way). Do you get the "NFC Scan7: ..." toast (in your updated code)? Is `rawMsgs != null`? Is `rawMsgs[0] != null`?

Comment: I thought the same thing. Unfortunately, it's not working the way I expect. I updated the code again and I'm getting the same result. When the app first runs, I see the Toast commands for NFC Scan1, NFC Scan4 then NFC Scan5. When I scan a tag with my external record, I see NFC Scan6, followed by NFC Scan1, NFC Scan4 then NFC Scan5....but never NFC Scan7. rawMsgs[0] should never be null, as that is intended to be my external record written in the array at location "0".

Comment: Is `onNewIntent()` invoked when you scan the tag? What's the value of `intent.getAction()` in `onNewIntent()`? Also, did you follow the advice in this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802 ?

Comment: Yes, onNewIntent is invoked upon scan. I've removed "getAction" from onNewIntent, as it was not necessary. I've tried to isolate my problem by only attempting to "read" the array. I'm still unable to do so...and I'm not sure why. I'm getting a NullPointer at "if (rawMsgs[0] != null)". I've added a couple of questions and notes by comment in my Manifest and Activity.

Comment: Your question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802. You are unable to receive the NDEF message from the tag because you never receive an NFC related intent (e.g. NDEF_DISCOVERED). Instead you always get an intent with action MAIN. Hence it **is** important that you check the intent action since you will only be able to process the data from the tag if you actually get an NFC intent! The reason why you don't receive the correct intent is because you use an invalid intent filter in your manifest.

Comment: Remove the line `android:mimeType=...` from your `<data />` element and remove the line `<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />` from the intent filter and you should receive the correct intent (assuming that your activity is newly created when tapping the tag).

Comment: I removed the lines suggested above and updated the code to show my entire manifest and activity. I'm still getting the same results, though. Does the "order" of my intents matter on the Manifest? I tried moving the "Main/Launcher" intent to the bottom, but still had the same results. If I remove them from the manifest altogether, obviously the app won't run. I'm still confused as to why I'm getting that NullPointer?

Comment: Is there any reason why you moved the `onNewIntent(getIntent());` from `onCreate()` to `onPause()`?

Comment: Yes, I was testing to see what would happen if I attempted to scan another tag while the app was running. I experience the same NullPointer in this situation, but rather than happening when the app "starts", it's happening upon the first scan of a tag.

Comment: After thinking about this for a while, I believe `onPause` is where the `onNewIntent` should actually be. A user won't have the array data until he/she scans the tag. I don't believe I should invoke `onNewIntent` from `onCreate`. Additionally, there will be many circumstances where the first scan will be to download the app in the Play Store via the AAR....and the second scan will be to actually access the array data.

Answer (score 0):

You mix togerthe message and record in your for loop. However there is only one NDEF message, but this message can hold several records. You must use only `rawMsgs[0]`. Then your for loop can iterate over all records of that message.

Comment: If I were to abandon the "for" loop, how could I simply read the external record at location 0? I don't need the "for" logic, rather I'm only evaluating the record once and then sending a user to a website corresponding to the value of that record. ie, if payloadString = 1, go to www.yahoo.com. ; if payloadString = 2, go to www.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [library](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android) which lets you parse NDEF records.

You're on the right track - wrapping binary paylod with using the external type - the library supports plugging in your own external type parser/record type(s), if you so prefer.

Comment: Please see my above comment, is there a component in your library that supports this kind of activity?

Comment: The library supports reading NDEF types - what you decide to do when you have read the payload is up to you and out of scope.