# NFC is launching app but intent is "action.MAIN" instead of "action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am able to launch my app using the NFC tag. Before I read data out of the tag in my activity I make sure that the intent action came from the NFC.

However, when I log the `intent.getAction()` it is always equal to `android.intent.action.MAIN` and not `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` as expected.

I am using this code in the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashscreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent->
</activity>
```

And determining the origin of the intent in the SplashscreenActivity like so:

```
public class SplashscreenActivity extends Activity {

     ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.w("NFC", "Intent is: " + intent.getAction());
     ...
}
```

I have configured the NFC chip myself and know that it contains the app package name, a text/plain value, and a URI. I have verified this using an NFC reader.

Comment: Override `onNewIntent()` and see if your `NDEF_DISCOVERED` `Intent` is delivered there.

Comment: i actually already have that, but for some reason it is never called

Comment: What data did you store on the tag? Is the first record on the tag really a Text record or MIME text/plain record? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802

Comment: the first record is currently the AAR, followed Text/plain and the URI. I will try to change the order as advised in that question.