# How to use NFC tag to open APP directly android

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I'm currently developing a solution that will replace QR codes. The QR codes work completely fine storing a custom URL that takes them directly into the app. This works both on Android and IOS with the same URL working on both platforms.

I have decided to use NFC tags aswell which works the same way as it does when using the QR codes.

**However, the problem is that the NFC tags when using an android phone pops up a URL to google instead of the app. I'm confused why the QR codes open the app directly but the NFC tags direct you to google.**

I have tried to research about but I'm stuck. Does the android app need an extra line of code to process the NDEF data to directly open when tapped?

The app isn't mine aswell so I will need to contact the developers if that's the case.

Thanks in advance and appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the NDEF type on the tag from URI to Android Application Record (AAR).
Check the [Android documentation on AAR](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar) for more info.

You may also look at [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510642/58848) for [this SO question on AAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504418/get-nfc-tag-with-ndef-android-application-record-aar)

Comment: For me it was enought to add `<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />` manifest record + configure deep linkinkg on the URL.