# Check if the app has been started by a NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

There is a way to understand if the app has been started by a NFC tag?

I have programmed a nfc tag for launching my app writing the app package name (with a third app) and i want to start a specific fragment in that case, how can i do that?

Comment: See [Get NFC tag with NDEF Android Application Record (AAR)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802)

Comment: @MichaelRoland My nfc tag have only a AAR record, so it's sure that my app will be lunched. I don't want to catch any other data from the tag nfc. How can i understand in my code if the app has been started by the nfc tag? thanks

Comment: Did you read the answer there (specifically the last paragraph)? And also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186762/2425802) for how to filter for the AAR itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an intent filter to an activity of your app, which registers that activity to be started by an nfc event. There are different ways to specify that filter, based on mime-type or technology etc.
Then in that activity, you can check in `onNewIntent()` and in `onResume()` if the intent that started the activity was an nfc intent.

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    setIntent(newIntent);
    // onResume is called afterwards, so we handle intent there
}

public void onResume() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText("NFC!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Here you could start your Fragment
    }
}
```

Please check the official documentation about the options you have for intent filters etc.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: Thanks. In the manifest i have added an intent filter that filter also for plain text and added a record to the nfc tag with text. Even if i don't need the text in the nfc tag this is the only method i found to properly start my app

Comment: You should be careful here as if the app goes to the background and comes to the foreground again later then the intent will still be the NFC intent due to setting it through setIntent(). The Tag in the intent would not be usable in that scenario I think. If you want you should setIntent() back to a MAIN launcher intent after processing to prevent scenarios like that occurring.

Comment: @jgriffin You are right, In my implementation, I call setIntent(null) at the end of onResume(), but that might not be the best solution.